# hg clone = HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo gazebo
```

> requesting all changes abort: HTTP 
> Error 400: Bad Request

Edit:  but these two commands are okay:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo-release
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models
```

And I can download the fuerte or john release ZIP file from the downloads page.

BitBucket has had some weird errors like this before...  can someone try the commands please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/859/hg-clone-=-http-error-400:-bad-request/) by [dbworth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/144/dbworth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Either bitbucket was down, or your network connection was. That command works for me.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/144/dbworth/) on 2013-01-17**:
It could be a strange network error in our area, but it only seems to be on the gazebo repo.

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-01-17**:
I'm able to clone gazebo without a problem, and so are our continuous integration machines, which clone it many times per day to run tests.  The problem might be at bitbucket's end, but without being able to reproduce it ourselves, I'm not sure how to help.

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/144/dbworth/) on 2013-01-17**:
Okay, I checked from home, same error. Perhaps you guys can ask BitBucket to fix the repo?  a quick Google search shows that error has appeared on other people's repo's. But, I guess most people compiling from source know how to get around this...

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-01-17**:
I've posted an issue at Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6015/user-unable-to-clone-osrf-gazebo.  I'll comment back here if/when I hear something on it.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-19**:
Can you clone another repo, such as https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim?